# MySQL - Left join with condition for matched row

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables User and Note

```
User
 id   name
 1    test1
 2    test2
 3    test3
```

```
Note
 id   user_id   memo
 1       1      ERROR
 2       2      SOMETHING
```

Then, I want to get all users from User table which are not existed in Note table and if it was existed in Note table, it should not have 'ERROR' and 'TEST' in memo column.

Expected data return:
`test3, test2`

I tried this:

```
SELECT User.id, User.user_name FROM User
LEFT JOIN Note ON User.id = Note.user_id
WHERE Note.memo NOT IN ('ERROR', 'TEST');
```

But It returned:
`test1, test2`

Then I tried this:

```
SELECT User.id, User.user_name FROM User
LEFT JOIN Note ON User.id = Note.user_id 
AND Note.memo NOT IN ('ERROR', 'TEST');
```

But it returned:
`test1, test2, test3`

So how can I get my expected result?

Comment: When you use a column from right table in WHERE (except `column IS NULL` condition) you convert your LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN. *But It returned: `test1, test2`* Must return `'test2'` only.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not really sure but I tried 2nd query as well and it didn't work. Beside, if 1st query is INNER JOIN why test 1 is returned?

Comment: Impossible. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a53c50e78bcf47c8b52b046c2405267d) (column name `User.user_name` fixed to `User.name` according to the table structure).

Comment: Yeah, the 2nd query should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM User
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM Note 
    WHERE User.id = user_id
      AND memo IN ('ERROR', 'TEST')
);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f0e379cd3f1d88c45502a7c87e7bdc7

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this one has the same result as my 2nd query.

Comment: @Mink You do something wrongly. Fiddle added.

Comment: Thank you, I have modified and it worked